# Python regex find multiple new line character "\n" the front and the back in the text

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm currently testing some regular expressions with python.
What I want to do is to extract a paragraph including a specific "keyword" in the text which was extracted from an html page. 
I found some ways of extracting a paragraph by recognizing that most paragraphs can be split with `"\n"`, `"\t"`, or `"\r"` like below.

```
re.finditer(r"([^\n^\t^\r]*?" + cor_word + r"[^\n^\t^\r]*)", html_text)
```

But I cannot find a way to extract a paragraph wrapped in multiple white space characters like paragraph "\n\n But it was not simple.\n\n". I want to extract paragraphs with multiple(more than 3) white space characters.

Is there anyone who can solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match whole paragraphs containing the word, where the paragraphs are defined as having more than one whitespace character around them then you can use the (something){0,2} to match 0 to 2 of something. 
You can then use .* to match all the characters around the word.
The regex bellow with match those with 3 or more:

```
re.finditer(r"([\n|\t|\r]{3,}.*" + cor_word + r".*[\n|\t|\r]{3,})", html_text)
```

If you want to be able to match from the beginning where the paragraph may not start with the returns then you can add a choice between the returns and a start character.

```
re.finditer(r"((?:[\n|\t|\r]{3,}|^).*" + cor_word + r".*[\n|\t|\r]{3,})", html_text)
```

Where (?: ) is a non-capturing group, which allows for the choice.(something){3,} matches 3 or more of something. [Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/9go29S/1)

If you wanted to match such that the number of whitespace on either side of the paragraph was the same this is something that can't be done in regular expressions. This is because regular expressions are equivalent to finite state automata which can not match languages such as n occurrences of 'a' followed by n occurrences of 'b'.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages)